# What is causing the White Strip as shown in Image in an ExpandableListView and how to correct this?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

[image: HeaderLayout][image: FragmentLayout][image: RowLayout][image: ProblemSeen]

There is this white vertical strip overlapping all the greenish imageviews as shown in the image. I am using API Level 14 and using ExpandableListView to do the code as shown in the image. Any Ideas?

Also the problem Happens only on API 14, but when I use an Emulator with API 21 everything seems to work fine.

Comment: add your layout file

Comment: `<ListView android:divider="#00000000" android:dividerHeight="0dp" .../> `

Comment: Nope this does not solve the problem. I am talking about the vertical strip that is overlapping all the imageviews/greenish views.

Comment: I think that's the child indicator. You should be setting it to `@null` rather than a color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `childIndicator` is rendered at the edge of the view. Typically this is a 9-patch for the "expand" icon, but in this case you have set it to be a color. You should set it to `@null` (or `@empty` if your SDK tools are up-to-date) if you do not want to show an indicator.

```
<ExpandableListView
    ...
    android:childIndicator="@null" />
```

As a side note, the `@empty` value was added in API 22 to indicate an explicit empty value, rather than `@null` which may result in a default value being used.